# Enable android databinding in offline enviornment

Tags: android, android-databinding

I need to use android data binding. My pc dose not have internet so i cannot use databinding =true.

I need to download the library jar file and copy to my pc. 
I cannot find the jar library any where. Any one knows where to download it.

Comment: There's not really a publicly browsable link to get it (and it's dependencies). You'd better off setting up the Android SDK on a machine that can download stuff, then move the files across

Comment: classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
use that one

Answer (score 1):

put data-binding library [3.2.1](https://maven.google.com/com/android/databinding/library/3.2.1/library-3.2.1.aar) into the `libs` directory - and add it as a regular `AAR` dependency:

```
api "com.android.databinding:library:3.2.1@aar"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** You don't need to have a databinding library as such. It's an inbuilt feature in Android Studio project.

You just have to enable it, nothing more.

I just went offline and created a project, enabled `databinding` by the below code and it worked fine.

Add this in your `build.gradle` a.k.a app level a.k.a second gradle from top:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Finally, `Sync now` and use databinding whether online or offline, doesn't matter.

Hope it's useful.

Comment: I already did. it gives android.databinding.ViewBinding class not found

Comment: @user93865 Okay, What is the use case and what all did you do?

Comment: As explained. I enabled databinding in gradle synched. Now tring to use ViewBinding class. it cannot see it

Comment: yes. Unable to resolve debendancy com.android.databinding.library:3.1.4

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the IDE and SDK installed?

Comment: IDE 3.1.4 and latest SDK 28

Comment: @user93865 Okay, Try in AS 3.2+ because I tried in same and I did not get any such error. What about your Build Tools section, are all the things installed?

Comment: I will try on 3.2. Every thing is installed

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the Google Maven repository at https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

From there you can reconstruct the artifact URLs you need. Here is a sample URL pattern that will download one of the AARs for databinding (they're aars, not jars): https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/library/3.1.4/library-3.1.4.aar

I'd get the POM for each of the databinding artifacts that you see in the index, to determine what else you need to pull: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/library/3.1.4/library-3.1.4.pom

It's pretty manual, but should do the trick if this is really what you need.

In general, I imagine it may be easier to use some fake build.gradle files with the dependencies you need on a machine with Internet access and then copy the populated gradle cache to your other machine. There also may be options to visualize the URLs Gradle uses to download the artifacts, so you don't have to hunt them down manually if you don't want to go the gradle cache route. Alternatively a similar scheme may be possible with a maven proxy like Sonatype Nexus.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this;

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
```

This is working for me.

Comment: Can i ask you something?

Comment: Why do you always answer apart from what is being asked and get a "-1"? I did not -1 that, I'm just curious to know.